# Im trying to host a minecraft server via docker and access the files

Tags: docker, minecraft

I'm trying to host a Minecraft server following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8uZB-ZMjdqM&ab_channel=TechCoreDuo) tutorial that uses this [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/itzg/minecraft-server). I typed up the command that he pulled up as follows:

```
docker run -d -p 25565:25565 --name mc -e EULA-TRUE --restart always -v /home/docker/minecraft/ data:/data itzg/minecraftserver
```

but I get the error

```
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

While trying to solve this issue I found [this](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) documentation on the docker website about mounting and volumes. I think that is what I want but I don't understand how I might use that to create an accessible folder to the container and its files. Will that command allows me to access the files on the server or do I need to do something else?

Comment: There are a few typos in your command line vs. what the tutorial shows e.g.  at [0:40](https://youtu.be/8uZB-ZMjdqM?t=40).

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. I changed it to `docker run -d -p 25565:25565 --name mc -e EULA=TRUE --restart always -v /home/docker/minecraft/_data:/data itzg/minecraft-server` and it does create the image but I still don't know how to access the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From docker doc:](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

> When you use a bind mount, a file or directory on the host machine is
> mounted into a container

That means, you can mount a local file or directory in your local machine into docker container filesystem. That means - All files and directories from the mounted localhost files or directories will be mounted to the docker container, and will override the docker container files if filenames are identical (same for directories).

**Important**: the docker container would also mount its files / directories to your local filesystem. However, in contrast to the opposite direction (local -> docker container), docker container would not override any files or directories in your local host file system.

And also as a note, If you want to avoid override a file from localhost to docker container filesystem you would use the most basic volume: anonymous volume.

From main comment seems you actually want to run the following:

```
docker run -d -p 25565:25565 --name mc -e EULA=TRUE --restart=always -v /home/docker/minecraft/_data:/data itzg/minecraft-server
```

I'm not into minecraft servers, but you should note you use in this command your local directory: `/home/docker/minecraft/_data`. I reckon you ensure it has the proper content (because it is going to be mounted to your docker container file system to `/data`. Or - this can be an empty folder in your local, and docker container would generate some data there so you will be able to look at this data later on.

Comment: So where is that data folder? I checked in the dir I ran the command in and all the docker related folders I could find it. Also, my bad about the typo. Like I said above I fixed it and it ran and created the container but I still don't understand how to get to the files.

Comment: @cperry Do you use windows / linux / macOS?

Comment: I use windows 10

Comment: @cperry Then, please attention to the synax of the command. Your data will be mounted to your local machine folder path:  `/home/docker/minecraft/_data`. This is implied from the command. How ever this is typically not a windows path. Possibly, you copied this command from someone.

This is very simple to solve. All you need to do is to create wherever you want, whatever filename you want - a folder. Suppose folder path is: `c:/data` then you need to run: `docker run -d -p 25565:25565 --name mc -e EULA=TRUE --restart=always -v c:/data:/data itzg/minecraft-server`

Comment: Ok. Will do. Let me go and try to run that command.

Comment: That worked!!! Thanks! Sorry again about the typo.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a mistake in your path, which seems to have a blank space before `data` directory : `/home/docker/minecraft/data:/data

```sh
docker run -d -p 25565:25565 --name mc -e EULA-TRUE --restart always -v /home/docker/minecraft/data:/data itzg/minecraftserver
```

With Docker, volumes are a way to store data. Everytime a container is downed, data not saved into volumes are lost.

Volumes can be setup by two ways :

- Docker-managed volumes
- Mounted path volumes

In your case, you declared `-v /home/docker/minecraft/data:/data`, which means **link my directory at `/home/docker/minecraft/data` with docker container directory `/data`**. So all data in there will persist and you will be able to add, modify or delete files.